# Titre de Sejour - Leaving France

Tags: visa, france

I wanted to ask a quite direct question that I can't find any answer to online.

What do you have to do with your Titre de Séjour (if it's still valid) if you leave France for another country? Is there something specific to do besides changing your postal address for example? Or notifying "les impots" and others?

I assume you can't have residency in two different EU countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything and your title remains valid unless the *préfecture* moves to invalidate it, which they are presumably entitled to do, as you probably do not fulfill the conditions anymore (e.g. you left your job or stopped your studies). As far as I know, they are happy to wait for the renewal or do a yearly sweep and are not super aggressive in invaliding cards of former residents. There is nothing that says that you cannot hold two residence permits or be considered a resident (for some purpose) in two EU countries, although it will usually be difficult to maintain that situation in the long run.

As far as I can tell, in France, the only obligation is to notify the tax office. It's also in your interest to notify utilities or the health insurance and many banks restrict common account to French tax residents (which you won't be anymore). Note that France doesn't even have a unified concept of “residence”. There are different definition of residence for different purposes. In principle, you could for example be considered a resident for tax purposes but not for nationality purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on which carte de sejour you actually have, whether UE or WARP (Withdrawal Agreement Residence Permit).

There are differing time limits for absence from the EU State in which you applied for a carte (5year carte and 10 year Carte have different absence time limits) and AFAIK there is nothing that requires you to give up your card since you absence/return will be recorded on entry/exit from the State and that will determine the continuing validity of your carte. The WARP does not confer any Freedom of Movement rights on the holder between States but the holder of a valid UE CdS will assume to have such rights through the nature of the Nationality in any event and accordingly may not need a residency card in their new State.

In that event, AFAIK there is nothing to prevent holding cards in more than one State except of course, that the time limits for application in a new State have now passed since you will no longer be in a position to have shown residency in the new State by the end of the transition period.

The carte remains the property of the EU issuing State and can be retained by them if demanded to be offered up.

EDIT: The OP mentions a Titre de sejour passeport talent in comments.

```
I assume you can't have residency in two different EU countries for example
```

IIRC, if you are no longer employed by the sponsoring employer, the validity of the TdS lapses.

Comment: Thanks for answering! :)

I have a Titre de sejour passeport talent (so 4 years), but what if I want to re-enter France (using my passport and not the titre, clearly)?

Comment: That's a different question entirely. Does [this reference](https://www.welcometofrance.com/en/fiche/talent-passport-highly-skilled-employees) help explain further? IIRC, if you are no longer employed by the sponsoring employer, the validity of the TdS lapses.

Comment: Sorry for not specify it before!
Actually, in France the TdS remains valid until the prefecture says the contrary, so that's why it's complicated to know what to do once you want to leave the country before the expiry date of the TdS. I don't have in mind coming back to work, but possibly yes for holidays or other things.
Thanks a lot for the answer and the reference!

Comment: If that addresses your question please consider [accepting it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "you absence/return will be recorded on entry/exit from the state": Not if you're moving to another Schengen state, and for the next couple of years not if you leave the Schengen area through a country other than France.  Also, reviewing https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16922 suggests that the end of employment does not invalidate the card.

Comment: @arsenelupin Entering France after your CdS is no longer valid depends on your nationality.

Comment: Thanks phoog. Actually I don’t require a visa for a temporary visit. But my fear is to receive an OQTF for example while I’m not living anymore in the country or something like that

Comment: @arsenelupin That's theoretically possible but I wouldn't be too concerned about that.